# Killing a process that is responsible for redirecting stdout to a file makes it a zombie

Tags: c, linux, signals, fork

I am redirecting the output of a program (program "exec'ed") with a forked process ("pipe2file") that handles the reading from the pipe and writing to a file.

If the program "exec'ed" is killed, and its wait status is reaped, the same needs to be done for the "pipe2file" process.
So, what I am doing exactly is this:

1. closing the end of the pipe that it used
2. sending a kill signal via `kill(pipe2file, SIGKILL)`
3. using waitpid to reap its exit status like this `waitpid(pipe2file, &status, 1)`
4. checking status with `if (WIFEXITED(status) || WIFSIGNALED(status))`

Still, after the above steps, the pipe2file process ends up a zombie.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have a race condition here. Calling `kill` may not kill your child straight away. It takes a moment.
You are not waiting long enough for your child to exit.

```
waitpid(pipe2file, &status, 1)
```

will give up if your child has not exited yet. The `1` in options is the `WNOHANG` option (e.g. don't wait until it has actually exited). Change it to

```
waitpid(pipe2file, &status, 0)
```

Comment: If I change the option to 0 then the program hangs at this wait. Why could the process responsible for reading from the pipe and writing to file, not being terminated? When the process using the write end, has already exited?

Comment: @Chris You'd have to post the source code of that process for me to tell you that. You can always attach a debugger to the child and see what it's doing.